# Icefaces 2 Plugin problem

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, icefaces

Hi i just download the plugin for helios but i am having a problems when it comes to download the icefaces-core library they dont appear.... could it be a firewall?? but why the others appear and the icefaces libs dont!! anyway i can do this manually??
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the latest version of the plugin includes the necessary icefaces jars, just select the JSF 2 version from ICEsoft and you should be ok. After creating a Dynamic Web Project, you can select the ICEfaces configuration. Once you do this the jars will be added to the project.